# java, hibernate: mapping property with a query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an entity with a property "quantity", this value is not a table field but is dynamically calculated with an hql query.

So, is possibile to add this value in my entities and make hibernate calculate it when I load my entities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculated property with JPA / Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You an use formula annotation. for example:

```
@Formula("(select min(o.creation_date) from Orders o where o.customer_id = id)")
private Date firstOrderDate;
```

See this post:
[Calculated property with JPA / Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate)

Se also Hibernate tutorial:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column

Comment: Be aware that the value might be outdated if the 2nd level cache is enabled for the entity!