# In JPA can I have a read only boolean for if a row exists?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-mvc

So to try to flesh it out a bit more... I have an object let's call User and I want to know if that user is an employee or not.  Employee's are their own object.  So what I want to do rather than have an employee object is to have a boolean that tells me whether or not that User is an employee.  I think this could be done with some form of readonly join?

Comment: A read only join? What does your database look like? Can you change it? (I.e., could you just add a boolean column to the user table)

Comment: no... i just want a boolean for if a row exists... basically i'm making up a column/variable based on whether or not a row exists.  I am just saying that i'd assume it would be a read only join

Comment: Can http://stackoverflow.com/a/2986354/692560 help you out? (Hibernate specific).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `@JoinColumn` to join the `User` object to an `Employee` object (you don't have to have more than the ID in it). You also don't need to have a getter for the Employee object, but you can now write an `isEmployee()` method that does the check `employee != null`. You probably want to make sure you use an eager fetch to always have the information there.

Answer (score 0):

JPA has a count functionality you can use in JPQL. You just have to make the distinction if it's an employee or not in your where clause.

Comment: i dont want to use jpql. i want it to just be jpa annotations or one method

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate getter method with @Transient and inside this method write logical operation, like if user_type is EMP then return true

Comment: i dont have access to the value... i need to get the value.

Comment: list me table names and its columns