# Hibernate derived property with xml mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, pojo

I have a `Detectable` class with a `Revisions` set, which are Hibernate managed POJOs. I'm also mapping my entities using *hbm.xml* files. When user goes to `Detectable` management screen, I want him to see `Detectable` data into a table, which will also contain the last `Revision` done. However the complete set of revisions will only be available accessing the detail page of the detectable.

My chance is to show the last revision date which will be loaded separately as an attribute with each `Detectable` instance. So I have something like that:

**detectable.hbm.xml**

```xml
<set name="_Revisions" table="trevision" inverse="true" lazy="true">
    <key>
        <column name="id_detectable" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.company.model.tasks.Revision" />
</set>

<property name="_LastRevisionDate"
        formula="select max(rev.start_date) from trevision rev where rev.id_detectable = _Id"
        type="date" />
```

That's not working and I have a SQL syntax error when hibernate tries to execute the query that is included in the **formula**. I've seen in different places that this property can be reached using [standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2986354/1199132) or [HQL](http://www.techienjoy.com/hibernate-property-formula-attribute.php) but I had failed with both of them. Also would it be possible to achieve the whole `Revision` entity (I mean the last revision) in order of the date only?

Pool your ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally achieved it with this code:

```xml
<property name="_LastRevisionDate"
        formula="(select MAX(rev.start_date) from trevision rev where rev.id_detectable = id_detectable and rev.status != 'DRAFT')"
        type="date" />
```

Where `id_detectable` is my current entity key column.

---

**UPDATE**

Another workaround is to [use a DB view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15918635/1199132) to obtain the last revision date. Then, there's the choice to map the Entity against that view instead of the original table.

Answer (score 1):

What is the sql syntax error? Did you try replacing `_Id` with `id`?

Comment: I tried. The sql syntax error is related to the query written in the formula, giving no more info. I can't find much more information about the derived properties, however this [link](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/using-derived-properties.html) suggests that hql can also be used. I'll check.

Comment: I just looked at some formula properties in our application and they are all wrapped in parens: `formula="(...)"`. Might be worth a try.

Comment: HQL or SQL? How do you reference the id of your current entity, by column name or attribute?

Comment: SQL. The column name and attribute are the same, `id`.

Comment: No problem. Did the parens fix it?