Can i retrieve the existing Roots of a view entity
Suppose I create a SQL View with different joins on multiple tables. I want to be able to perform different filters on this view using Criteria API. Since I have already included joins in the sql view definition, can i access the roots of the supposed entities for specific filtering?

You can only filter a view on the columns that it exposes

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913238/hibernate-criteria-is-it-possible-to-access-a-database-view-with-criteria
