# Hibernate derived Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working in a Java application using Hibernate 3.6.9 as ORM and xml mappings. Actually, having two entities, **Detectable** and **Revision**, **Detectable** has a one-to-many relation with **Revision**, having its entire set of done revisions mapped:

```xml
<set name="_Revisions" table="trevision" inverse="true" lazy="true">
    <key>
        <column name="id_detectable" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.company.model.tasks.Revision" />
</set>
```

Refer also to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813118/hibernate-derived-property-with-xml-mapping) I posted. What I want now is to get the last of that revisions in a separate field of the class:

```xml
<many-to-one name="_LastDoneRevision" column="id_detectable"
            class="com.company.model.tasks.Revision" lazy="false" />
```

What I want to achieve with that is to have the last revision (which I use in most of the cases) always eagerly fetched. Apart from that I could get the whole set of Revisions if I want, but it's lazily initialized by default. To achieve this, it might be necessary to use a custom query to get the last revision done from the whole set.

I think that can't be achieved with formulas, because they just retrieve a value, not a whole Entity. I want to be able in some way to choose what the `many-to-one` relation should have.

A solution could be [to use a view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177416/1199132) instead of the **Detectable** table itself. That way I could have a **VDetectable** entity which would be mapped against the view and the view could obtain all the original attributes plus the reference to the **Revision** I'm interested in.

Anyway, is it possible to have it loaded using only the original entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont promise its efficient or even the right way to do it, but I have done a similar thing like this...

```
<many-to-one 
  name="theMaxSetting"
  class="myPath.domain.Setting"             
  formula="(select MAX(s.SETTING_ID) from setting s where s.profile_id = PROFILE_ID)"
/>
```

In my case, a profile has many settings. The formula is a bit tricky to get right, but basically the formula returns a number, and hibernate uses that number to lookup the corresponding entity.

Just to state the obvious in case ... Profile.java now contains

```
private Setting theMaxSetting;
//....
//getter / setter
```

This [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html) shows various examples of the use of formula. Some examples demonstrate how it is used with  sql queries, others demonstrate that it can be used to return an entity. I dont think there is one that combines them into a single use case, but all the pieces are there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll be grateful if you would be able to provide some reference in the web where this method is shown being applied.

Comment: Thanks for the link, anyway I didn't know a formula could be used in that way (if you take a look to the reference, it only shows examples with entity properties and not the id itself). It works properly, I'm just going to wait if anybody provides a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a formula is the solution you want. Just provide Hibernate with a formula that computes the primary key of the entity you want to link. I guess your xml will look like:

```
<many-to-one name="_LastDoneRevision"
    class="com.company.model.tasks.Revision" lazy="false">
  <formula>
    (select max(r.id_revision)
    from revision r
    where r.id_detectable = id_detectable)
  </formula>
</many-to-one>
```