# update attribute for property element in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

The property element of Hibernate has attributes update, insert and as per documentation it states that - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property

> update, insert (optional - defaults to true): specifies that the
>   mapped columns should be included in SQL UPDATE and/or INSERT
>   statements. Setting both to false allows a pure "derived" property
>   whose value is initialized from some other property that maps to the
>   same column(s), or by a trigger or other application.

Please help me in understanding how it behaves if its value is set as 'false' instead of 'true'. What is the derived property here?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the difference in an example - if you create an entity and persist it using default `insert` settings, all fields that the entity has set will be persisted, and you will see in Hibernate log the expected generated insert SQL statement. Something like:

```
Hibernate: insert into SCHEMA1.User (id, firstName, lastName) values (default, ?, ?)
```

But if you set `insert` for some property to false, even if the field has value in the entity, the generated SQL will have the appropriate column excluded, so the value for it won't be persisted. If the *firstName* has `insert` set to false, the generated SQL is:

```
Hibernate: insert into SCHEMA1.User (id, lastName) values (default, ?)
```

This will work if *firstName* is nullable, and fail otherwise.

The described principle also applies to `update`.

Setting these attributes to false makes sense in the case mentioned in docs, where you deal with a derived (calculated) property that you do not persist. It is in fact a read-only property with value computed at fetch time (computation is declared as an SQL expression which translates to a SELECT subquery). You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate) post for an example and links for more information about derived properties.