# @Formula seems not working in Hibernate 4?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, seam

We have migrated our project to use the latest version of hibernate which is 4.1.6 and seam which is 3.2 and JPA 2.1 . We Are having problem with the @Formula annotation. It seems that the right SQL is executed from the SQL output but the property value returns null. I dont know if these is dependency issue or anything. If you guys know it will be a big help

Here is the snapshot of the property.

```
@Formula(value="(select crs.name from EntityName crs where crs.id = id)")
public String getName() {
    System.out.println(" name set -- " + name);
    return name;
}
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: The Formula annotation supports SQL only. You seem to be attempting to use HQL.

Comment: It works with [HQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate) too. Is the @Id set to a getter too, right? If you are using property-access you need to have all mapping annotations applied to properties.

Comment: This code actually works when using hibernate 3.x version, now when we use version 4 it does not set the value anymore. All of our property with @Formula does not work.

Comment: I am having the same problem, over a year later. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No i havent, fortunately we did not pursue with the migration. :)

Comment: Too bad. We have the same issue :(

Comment: I haven't found any thing related to this anymore and i have not tried it either so far. If you managed to find out something, please post it here, it will help others too. Thank you. :)