# How to convert SQL Query using CriteriaQuery in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I want to convert my sql query from SQL to Criterias (i dont want to use JPQL), i have this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',p.first_name, p.middle_name, p.last_name) AS fullname FROM persons p) AS tmp
WHERE fullname LIKE '%cetina avila%' ORDER BY fullname;
```

How is the best way to do this?, Im trying to search full names from my talbe persons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an @Formula mapping on your Person class like this

```
@Formula("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', middle_name, ' ', last_name)")
private String fullname;
```

Then in your Criteria you can search it like any normal field.

See [Calculated property with JPA / Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate) for more on calculated fields.