# Function result AS class field value

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL database, in which there is a function `month_traffic()`

```
CREATE FUNCTION month_traffic(hostcode int) RETURNS numeric(14,2) AS $$
DECLARE
start_date date := CAST((EXTRACT(year FROM now()) || '-' || EXTRACT(month FROM now()) || '-' || '01') AS date);
end_date date := CAST((EXTRACT(year FROM now()) || '-' || EXTRACT(month FROM now()) + 1 || '-' || '01') AS date); 
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT SUM(day_mbytes) FROM daily WHERE (day_hstcode = hostcode) AND (day_date >= start_date) AND (day_date < end_date));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I also have `Host` class

```
package ru.gooamoko.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;

@Entity
@Table(name="hosts")
public class Host implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="hst_pcode")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="hst_grpcode", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Department group;

    @Column(name="hst_description", length=50, nullable=false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name="hst_net", nullable=false)
    private short net;

    @Column(name="hst_addr", nullable=false)
    private short addr;

    @Column(name="hst_ballance", nullable=false, columnDefinition="numeric(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
    private float ballance;

    @Column(name="hst_price", nullable=false, columnDefinition="numeric(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
    private float price;

    @Column(name="hst_enabled", nullable=false, columnDefinition="boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name="hst_still", nullable=false, columnDefinition="boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false")
    private boolean steel;

  // daily traffic
  private transient float dayKBytes = 0;
  // monthly traffic
  private transient float monthMBytes = 0;
  // Setters and getters
  // . . .
}
```

Is it possible to set result of postgresql function as field value for monthMBytes like

```
// month traffic
@Formula("(select month_traffic(hst_pcode)")
private transient float monthMBytes = 0;
```

Best regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read it and confused - is it HQL or native SQL in the `@formula` annotation. All I was need is to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read related SO questions, some documentations and...

1. I need to make field non-transient.
2. I don't need field setter. Only getter enought.
3. In the @Formula annotation I write sql query that selects value from function.
4. PostgreSQL function **must** return **NOT NULL** value.

So, my new function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION month_traffic(hostcode int) RETURNS numeric(14,2) AS $$
DECLARE
  begin_date date := CAST((EXTRACT(year FROM now()) || '-' || EXTRACT(month FROM now()) || '-' || '01') AS date);
  end_date date := CAST((EXTRACT(year FROM now()) || '-' || EXTRACT(month FROM now()) + 1 || '-' || '01') AS date);
  result numeric(14,2) := 0;
BEGIN
  result := (SELECT SUM(day_mbytes) FROM daily 
    WHERE (day_hstcode = hostcode) AND (day_date >= begin_date) AND (day_date < end_date));
  IF (result IS NULL) THEN
    result := 0;
  END IF;
  RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

and my annotated field is

```
  . . .
  @Formula("(select month_traffic(hst_pcode))")
  private float monthMBytes;

  public float getMonthMBytes() {
    return monthMBytes;
  }
  . . .
```

And everything now works fine. Thanks for the links and comments.