# JDO/DataNucleus: map/calculate derived field

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

Question in short: How can you map/calculate a derived field using JDO/DataNucleus?

## Example

An `Order` can have one or more `Items`. The field `totalItemAmount` is the sum of all `Items` and their `amounts`. `totalItemAmount` should not exist as a field in the datastore, but should be calculated.

[image: class diagram of Order and Item]

With Hibernate one could use `@Formula` to annotate `totalItemAmount`- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2986354/2294031 .

Is there an equivalent for JDO/DataNucleus?

## Workarounds

Because I have not found anything yet, I considered using alternative approaches. But I am not sure which one would be appropriate.

1. Implementing `totalItemAmount` as a method: The total amount of items could be calculated with a method (eg. `Order.getTotalItemAmount()`). The method iterates over all `Items` of the `Order` and sums up the `amount` of each `Item`. But I imagine this approach would be very slow if I want to display an overview of many orders. Because each time `getTotalItemAmount()` gets called, all `Items` of the `Order` will be (unnecessarily) fetched.
2. Defining a custom query: Is it possible to define a custom query, which will be used, when DataNucleus obtains `Orders` from the datastore?
3. Treating `totalItemAmount` as a "normal" column (like `number`): `totalItemAmount` will be an integer column and everytime the list of `Items` from the `Order` gets updated, the `totalItemAmount` will be updated also. But I do not like this approach, because it could lead to inconsistency - If the order gets modified outside the context (eg. using plain SQL), the content of `totalItemAmount` could be wrong.
4. Using a SQL view: I could define a view as described in [Hibernate Derived Properties - Performance and Portability](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_derived_properties_performance_and). But this would introduce a considerable amount of work and future maintenance - imho too much for the gain.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

*Off-Topic:* Feel free to comment on my writing, as I really would like to improve it.

Comment: So you need to know when an object is instantiated? ... JDO has lifecycle listeners (and postLoad callback) for that and you can do what you want in your class.

Comment: @NeilStockton Not exactly - I would prefer to use something similar as '@Formula'. Because if I use `postLoad` to calculate `totalItemAmount` all `Items` have be fetched. This would certainly take a lot of time for many `Orders`, wouldn't it?
But if this is not possible your input will certainly help with workaround 1 and 3 - thank you.

Comment: Well PostLoad tells you when an object is loaded, and you can easily fire off a query at that point and assign that field to the result of the query ... same thing as Formula does AFAIK

Comment: @NeilStockton According to http://blog.eyallupu.com/2009/07/hibernate-derived-properties.html `@Formula` works differently - see section "Performance". But I will try it nevertheless.