# Best way to get aggregate function result inside the entity object

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, aggregate-functions, jpa-2.1

Many time I have to get the SQL aggregate query result inside the Entity Object itself. As of now I could able to achive the same by the following code

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> q = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<Test> c = q.from(Test.class);
    q.multiselect(c, cb.count(c));
    q.groupBy(c.get("type"));

    TypedQuery<Tuple> t = em.createQuery(q);
    List<Tuple> resultList = t.getResultList();
    List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Tuple tuple : resultList){
        Test te = (Test) tuple.get(0);
        te.setQuantity((long)tuple.get(1));
        list.add(te);
    }
```

But I want to know what could be the best way. My Test Entity is as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type = 0;

    @Transient
    private long quantity;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2986354/1356423

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculated property with JPA / Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: How do I can achieve dynamic select criteria on a annotation. Apart from group by , I will be having conditional select. So I dont think its a good option to use the Formula, which is usually used for Derived values not for aggregate functions.

Comment: If I can use dynamic select conditions as well group by in Formula let me know how can I do it. Can you give me an example for the exact requirment where i need to add dynamic predicates on it.

Comment: You should either add a new question or edit your existing question if you think that your original question did not hit the point. It is difficult to understand what you mean with "conditional select". What kind of condition do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `@Formula` then I'd suggest create a database view basic on your select and mapping an additional entity to that. You can then map this to your existing entity using either as a `@OneToOne` or by using `@SecondaryTable`.

This has the added advantage of being JPA compliant (i.e. not using Hibernate's propreitary @Formula) and would look something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type = 0;

    @OneToOne//or via secondary table
    private TestSummaryInfo summaryInfo;

    public long getQuantity(){
        return summaryInfo.getQuantity();
    }
}
```

Summary mapped to a view:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vw_test_summary")
public class TestSummaryInfo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Long quantity;
}
```