# How is more correct to get this data with spring-data-jpa?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

For example I need show statistic table on web page. This table consists of 5 rows:

```
AVG-rating | 5
TotalSum   | 12.1
SumToday   | 2.1
SummMonth  | 8.6
SomeElse   | 666
```

Each value in this table - calculated using an aggregate function in a database.

**Question**: How is more correct to get this data with `spring-data-jpa`?

Now I have One service - `StatisticService` with public methos `getStatistic(user);`

In this method I call `5 methods` from `repository` for each statistic value and form response. Each repository method - `native query`.

I do not like this aproach. And I think best way is create `View` in `database` and select all statistic **in one query to view**.

But this aproach I do not like too. Because I'm tied to the base. and the base contains logic. Although in the first case I use native queries, but I can rewrite them to `JPQL` (but maybe not all).

How to more correctly extract aggregated information from the database with `spring-data-jpa`?

Comment: I would create a view and map it to the Entity using `@SecondaryTable` and then they just become normal properties of the entity. The big advantage of this approach is that you can sort and filter at the database level using standard repository methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778895/best-way-to-get-aggregate-function-result-inside-the-entity-object/33782331#33782331

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all the values calculated inside DB I do not see any opportunities rather than you call every 5 queries. Otherwise you need to implement this calculation logic inside your code