# Failed to create sessionFactory object: java.lang.IllegalStateException HQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have try this one in many ways finally i found a way but it is not working on linux environment following HQL is that

```
SELECT es.eventId as eventId, MAX(es.raisedTimestamp) as raisedTimestamp, es.id as id, es.isReset as isReset FROM EsEvent es WHERE es.isReset=1 GROUP BY es.eventId ORDER BY es.raisedTimestamp DESC
```

this will end up with the enabled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode in mysql.

so that i added ANY_VALUE() function to my hql below one is that.

```
SELECT es.eventId as eventId, MAX(es.raisedTimestamp) as raisedTimestamp, ANY_VALUE(es.id) as id, es.isReset as isReset FROM EsEvent es WHERE es.isReset=1 GROUP BY es.eventId ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(es.raisedTimestamp) DESC
```

in this case it will end up with HQL exception like this

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('|  +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'ANY_VALUE' {originalText=ANY_VALUE}|  \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'|     \-[DOT] DotNode:'esevent0_.ID'{propertyName=id,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=id,path=es.id,tableAlias=esevent0_,className=org.reactor.monitoring.model.entity.EsEvent,classAlias=es}|        +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'esevent0_.ID' {alias=es, className=org.reactor.monitoring.model.entity.EsEvent, tableAlias=esevent0_} |        \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'id' {originalText=id}
```

please any one can help me to fix this out. it is really helpful and if you can give me reason behind this it's highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ANY_VALUE()` with HQL.

But you can

1. Use it with the native SQL https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/
2. Add `ANY_VALUE()` as the custom function to HQL
   [How to use native sql function with HQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35930600/how-to-use-native-sql-function-with-hql-query)