# Can I use JPA to mapping field from a query result

Tags: jpa

I am curious whether I can write something like this in JPA?

Or, Hibernate has such extension?

Or, @PostLoad has such equivalent?

Or, we must write separate DAO/Repository/Service?

```
@Entity
class Foo {

  @Id
  long id;

  @Basic
  String name;

  @Transit
  // Query("select address from Address a where a.username = this.name + '000' "
  String address;

}
```

Even more

```
@Entity
class Bar {

  @Id
  long id;

  @Basic
  String code;

  @Basic
  String name;

  @Transit
  // Query("select name from Bar b where b.code = substr(this.code, 0, 2) + '0000' "
  String provinceName;

  @Transit
  // Query("select name from Bar b where b.code = substr(this.code, 0, 4) + '00' "
  String cityName;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate has the `@Formula` annotation that might just be what you're looking for. This is not standard JPA though. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate) for details.