# How to use Postgresql functions in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have this query and it is working as i expected

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(id) as views_per_day,
  view_date::timestamp::date,
  extract(dow from view_date::timestamp::date) as day_index
FROM details 
WHERE view_date > current_date - interval '6' day
GROUP BY view_date::timestamp::date
ORDER BY view_date::timestamp::date;
```

I am using Hibernate in my project but i am a Hibernate newbie. What i want to know is how can i use functions like

```
`extract(dow from view_date::timestamp::date)`, 
`interval '6' day` `view_date::timestamp::date`
```

in Hibernate or is there a way to run this as a raw sql without security vulnerabilities ? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try to write native queries in hibernate and use any native function it to get the results. you may google it (How to write sql Native queries in Hibernate) @Tartar

Comment: Look into using `createNativeQuery()` which will execute a raw SQL query.  I believe you'll need to go down this road, since the Postgres functions you are trying to use are not standard HQL.

Comment: Another option is to define this as a view in the database, so you can query it without calling the functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `@Formula`-annotation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate).

```
@Formula("extract(dow from view_date::timestamp::date)")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13040525)

Comment: Blind Prophet, i do not understand. The question is clear, no need to critique or request for clarification. This is an answer!

Answer (score 0):

or use createNativeQuery() and you can use your query as it is.