# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column xxx in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Java 8 with JPA/Hibernate 5.2.1 and a MySQL database.

**Tables:**

```
+--------+    +----------------+    +----------+ 
| Rating |    | Rating_Employee|    | Employee |
+--------+    +----------------+    +----------+ 
| ID     |    | RAT_ID         |    | ID       |
| REVIEW |    | EMP_ID         |    +----------+ 
+--------+    +----------------+
```

I am trying to save a row in a `Rating` table, but get the following:

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'employee0_.distance' in 'field list'
```

The reason is because the Employee model object has a `DISTANCE` field, but no matching column on the database.  I need the `DISTANCE` field because when I do a `SELECT` on the Employee table, I calculate the `DISTANCE` based on other columns with a `nativeQuery`. However, when Hibernate does the select itself when updating the joined table `RATING`, it wants to match `DISTANCE`, which does not exist (I get the above error).

When I `persist` or `merge` the Employee object, I use the following successfully:

```
@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private BigDecimal distance;
```

**Question:**

How do I get Hibernate to ignore the `DISTANCE` when doing a non native query `select`? (When it updates `RATING` table)

**UPDATE**

I was advised to possibly use `@Formula("...")`, but my method has a pretty complex `nativeQuery`, which also order by `distance`.  If I put the formula into `@Formula("...")`, it needs to also receive parameters currently passed to the method.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a Hibernate @Formula column to retrieve the distance via a native SQL query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate

Comment: Thanks Alan, I will have a look.

Comment: Hi Alan, my problem with using `@Formula`, is that I need to order the result set by `distance`. I cannot retrieve it, and sort it in java because I am only getting a limited number of rows at a time. Do you have any ideas? Is it possible to `order by` the `@Formula` column?

Comment: Is it possible to toggle a field `@Transient` dynamically via reflection at runtime? His anyone had experience with [Javassist](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.co.za/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html)?

Comment: Javassist won't work for me because at runtime, I would have to create a new class loader to get its effects.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate only ignore fields annotated with @Transient. Thus, you can use this option to make the field "distance" not managed by hibernate

```
@Transient
private BigDecimal distance;
```

from java doc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html

Comment: Hi SEY_91, thanks but, `@Transient` would normally work, but I need to do this dynamically. When I do a `select` (`nativeQuery`) on the Emplyee table, I need the `distance` field. So I can't just make it `@Transient`.

Comment: If you mean by "the distance field for only native query" that you want to get "distance column" created when hibernate create the schema and after that it will not be mapped by hibernate query. then you can create manually the column "distance" because doing that dynamically(at runtime ignoring specific fields) is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I think I am going to write a native query to do the INSERT.

Comment: I am having problems with a native query, because the save is done in a transaction. I cannot retrieve the rating `id` because it has not been committed yet by the the time I need to know what the `id` is. (I need the `id` to `insert` into the join tables)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I make a second Employee object that does not have `@Transient` on distance. I then use that and copy it to the Employee object.

```
List<Employee> employees = new <Employee>ArrayList();
List<EmployeeWithDistance> employeesWD = (List<EmployeeWithDistance>) q.getResultList();
for (EmployeeWithDistance employeeWD : employeesWD) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(employeeWD, employee);
    employees.add(employee);
}
return employees;
```