# How set update expression on field for dynamodb?

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-dynamodb

Loot at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2986354/1251549) hibernate supports to set custome sql expression for class fields. Is there something similar for dynamodb mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any if there is an option. The closest I got to was using this library

https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb

and the wiki for that

https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Supported-Spring-Data-Comparison-Operators

and example of how I have used it is

```
someRepository.queryBySomeKeyAndUpdateNumberGreaterThan(key, randomNumber)
```