# Binding selected (and transformed) column to entity field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have hibernate query, where I need to transform one column with date_trunc, however I don't know how to bind this transformed value to my joined entity object

Is there any possibility to pass this transformed column to mine hibernate entity?

Of course it's conceptual code in case it wouldn't make sens for you:

```java
    @Entity
    class SomeClass {
         private ZonedDateTime orderTime;

         @ManyToOne(targetEntity = SomeStats.class)
         @JoinColumn(name = "SOME_STATS_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
         private SomeStats someStats; // Class that I need aggregate

         private long id;

         // ... other fields that aren't grouped
   }
```

```java
   class SomeStats {
       private long id;
       private double price; // I need to take average of this
       private ZonedDateTime paymentTime; // And truncate this
   }
```

I need some idea to make something similar to:

```sql
SELECT someclass.*, AVG(somestats.price), date_trunc('hour', somestats.payment_time) as timebucket
FROM SOME_CLASS someclass 
JOIN SOME_STATS somestats ON somestats.id = someclass.some_stats_id
GROUP BY someclass.id, timebucket
```

but with average as SomeStats.price and truncated date as SomeStats.paymentTime, is it even possible?

Comment: You can use jpa [AttributeConverter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-jpa-convert) or hibernate [custom type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type).

Comment: I'd like to, however I use this only for selects in that **one** particular query...

Comment: Could you please provide a query (at least simplified version).

Comment: I suppose `@Formula` can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/how-to-map-calculated-properties-with-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: Share your code if possible

Comment: Ok, I've made some conceptual entities.

Comment: Where do you get this error "SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
The column name time was not found in this ResultSet." Please show the query and the code

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - It wasn't related, I'm sorry... My initial assumption was wrong. I need to aggregate joined entity field in typesafe way, is there any chance?

Comment: I dont' understand your requirement. Can you please add some more details

Comment: I want to get joined entity as object in java with aggregated value from DB